# Data is not storing in database in cakephp

Tags: cakephp

Data is not storing in database in cakephp it is directly going into else if part is not working.

```
if ($this->request->is('post')) {
        $this->Reg->create('User');
        // pr($this->Reg->save($this->request->data['user']['firstname']));
        if ($this->Reg->save($this->request->data)) {

            $this->Flash->set("The Topic has been created!");
                $this->redirect(array('action' => 'Reg'));
        } else {
            $this->Flash->set("The Topic has not  been created!");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: can you please print $this->Reg->validationErrors; in else part?

Answer (score 1):

The save is failing, mostly because of validation errors.

Before this line:

`$this->Flash->set("The Topic has not been created!");`

add in

`pr($this->Reg->validationErrors)`

and see what the result is

Comment: try this `$result = $this->Reg->save($this->request->data); pr($result)`

Answer (score 0):

Please check __ function.
http://api.cakephp.org/3.1/function-__.html
Basically it is return the text into string.